# Why keyboard hide automatically when Web service is in progress?

Tags: ios, swift, web-services, keyboard, uitextfield

In chat screen , we implemented a Web Api which is continuously called after each 6 seconds. When keyboard is appeared to write message and on other side WebApi is called, keyboard disappearing quickly.Please help me to Solve this issue.

Comment: may be you are calling reload data in web service completion block and may be the textField in focus is a part of cell. All in may be because we have no idea of your code

Comment: The textfield is a part of table view
?

Comment: The textfield is not a part of tableview.yes i'm reloading the data of tableview with dispatch , but textfield is not on tableview.